# Printing a JAXB generated bean

Tags: java, logging, jaxb, javabeans, tostring

I have a JAXB data class which is generated from `wsimport` and I'd like to print it to the console and/or log. Unfortunately a toString is not generated.

What's the easiest way to print the data object? It doesn't matter whether the output is the original XML or something else, as long as it's readable.

It looks like the class is a valid bean (properly named getters and setters) so anything that works with beans is probably fine too.

Answer (score 3):

For printing to the console, try this:

```
jaxbContext.createMarshaller().marshal(jaxbObject, System.out);
```

To get it into a `String`, use a `StringWriter`:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
jaxbContext.createMarshaller().marshal(jaxbObject, writer);
String xmlString = writer.toString();
```

To get the JAXBContext object you need to do the following:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(<WhateverClass>.class);
```

Where `<WhateverClass>` is the class literal for the type that `jaxbObject` is. You should also be able to do:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(jaxbObject.getClass());
```

Depending on where you are defining the context and your stylistic preference. `JAXBContext` is thread-safe so it is good to define one instance and share it. `Marshaller` and `Unmarshaller` make no such guarantees though. So they need to be created on demand.

Comment: Where do you get `jaxbContext`?

Comment: @Bart you've to pass a list of package names where this object can be found, to get an instance of [JAXBContext](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html).

Comment: @asgs - You can pass classes or package names (where the package contains a `jaxb.index` file or `ObjectFactory`) to create a new `JAXBContext`.

Comment: @Blaise Thanks for the info. I just understood that from the Java Docs.